# Flutter Firebase Autenticación (Bloc+Provider+StreamBuilder)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-auth

les cuento

Estoy haciendo una app en la cual estoy intentando realizar la autenticación del usuario a través de Firebase mediante Google. Estoy usando la arquitectura Bloc junto con Clean Arquitecture (lo aprendí hace poco en un curso).

La cuestión es que en mi StreamBuilder, cuando el en stream llamo al método "authStatus" el cual debería devolverme la siguiente instancia: "FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()" me devuelve siempre "null" y no estoy entendiendo el porque de esto. A continuación dejo el link del git con el códgio y capturas del código por sí es un error muy básico que no estoy encontrado que a simple vista se vea. Desde ya muchas gracias

https://github.com/GasparCarp11/Initium

[image: Inicializo todo lo referido a FireBase]

[image: Creo el método SignIn]

[image: Toda la lógica Bloc]

[image: Mi pantalla de Sign In donde está mi StreamBuilder]

Comment: Por favor coloca el código como texto y no como imagen. Saludos.

Comment: Perdona, soy nuevo usando la plataforma. En esta pregunta lo deje como texto, gracias por la sugerencia y por la dedicación. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/390115/flutter-firebase-autenticaci%c3%b3n-blocproviderstreambuilder

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación aparece esta implementación:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

Porque no pruebas hacerlo así y ver que está pasando?

Documentación:
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/