# Flutter Firebase Autenticación (Bloc+Provider+StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

estoy haciendo una app en la cual estoy intentando realizar la autenticación del usuario a través de Firebase mediante Google. Estoy usando la arquitectura Bloc junto con Clean Arquitecture (lo aprendí hace poco en un curso).

La cuestión es que en mi StreamBuilder, cuando el en stream llamo al método "authStatus" el cual debería devolverme la siguiente instancia: "FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()" me devuelve siempre "null" y no estoy entendiendo el porque de esto. A continuación dejo el link del git con el códgio y el código mismo. Desde ya agradezco cualquier comentario o ayuda. Saludos

```css
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      bloc: UserBloc(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Initium',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        // home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        home: SignInScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class FirebaseAuthAPI {
  final auth.FirebaseAuth _auth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<auth.User> signIn() async {
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication gSA = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
    auth.UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(
        auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            idToken: gSA.idToken, accessToken: gSA.accessToken));
    return userCredential.user;
  }
}


class AuthRepository {
  final _firebaseAuthAPI = FirebaseAuthAPI();
  Future<FirebaseUser> signInFirebase() => _firebaseAuthAPI.signIn();
}



class UserBloc implements Bloc {
  final _auth_repository = AuthRepository();

  Stream<User> streamFirebase = FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges();

  Stream<User> get authStatus => streamFirebase;

  Future<FirebaseUser> signIn() {
    return _auth_repository.signInFirebase();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {}
}


class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() {
    return _SignInScreenState();
  }
}

class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {
  UserBloc userBloc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserBloc userBloc = BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context);
    return _handleCurrentSession();
  }

  Widget _handleCurrentSession() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: userBloc.authStatus,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.hasError) {
          return signInGoogleUI();
        } else {
          return HomeScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget signInGoogleUI() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          GradientBack("", null),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Bienvenido.\nA tu aplicacion de pedidos",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28.0,
                  fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              ),
              Button(
                text: "Inicia con Google",
                onPressed: () {
                  userBloc.signIn().then((FirebaseUser user) =>
                      print("El usuario es ${user.displayName}"));
                },
                heigth: 50.0,
                width: 300.0,
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Flutter Firebase Autenticación (Bloc+Provider+StreamBuilder)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/390048/flutter-firebase-autenticaci%c3%b3n-blocproviderstreambuilder)

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación aparece esta implementación:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

Porque no pruebas hacerlo así y ver que está pasando?